# Не правильно ли будет писать две одинаковые переменные в разных областях видимости?

Tags: javascript

допустим вот так:

```
{
let arrayIndex;
}

...

{
let arrayIndex;
}
```

переменные берут индекс массива, ну делают это в разных функциях

Comment: почему это должно быть неправильно?

Comment: @Grundy Здравствуйте разве это не блок кода ?

Comment: @Leks, что _это_?

Comment: @Leks область видимости объявленной через let переменной будет блок кода, поэтому на вопрос это не влияет.

Answer (score -1):

вы же уже let используете.
Вы ходит что переменная будет видна только в рамках {} где обозначена.
https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const